# Django Admin - Multiple Inlines

Tags: django, django-admin

Having a bit of trouble using multiple inlines within my admin console over 3 models which im playing around with.

Models:

```
class carManufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class vehicleModel(models.Model):
    carManufacturer = models.ForeignKey(carManufacturer)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.model

class vehicleCode(models.Model):
    vehicleModel = models.ForeignKey(vehicleModel)
    variantCode = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    variantBadge = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    manuStart = models.DateTimeField('Manufacture Start Date')
    manuFin = models.DateTimeField('Manufacture End Date')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.variantCode
```

What I'm looking to do is when I add a car Manufacturer I can add car Models via my inline, and when I am editing models, I can edit vehicle codes/variants via another inline.

I have an admin.py file I am using:

```
from Cars.models import carManufacturer, vehicleModel, vehicleCode
from django.contrib import admin

class modelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = vehicleModel
    extra = 0

class codeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    variantCode = vehicleCode
    extra = 0


class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name',  'description', 'country']
    inlines = [modelInline]

class VehicleModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['carManufacturer','model']
    #inlines = [codeInline]


admin.site.register(carManufacturer, CarAdmin)
admin.site.register(vehicleModel, VehicleModelAdmin)
```

As soon as I uncomment my second inline which uses the same method as the first I get the following error:

> 'model' is a required attribute of 'VehicleModelAdmin.inlines[0]'.

I am struggling to understand what I am doing wrong, especially since I have got the first inline working, any input would be much appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but `model` (listed in `fields`) could collide with another property of `ModelAdmin` class. Try to change it to something else

Comment: The codeInline doesn't have model field for any TabularInline you do need model field like one above.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, changing it from variantCode to model worked. What is the significance of the model field @SidharthShah Is it something which inline needs to operate? I think I am getting confused between django keywords and my own fields!

Comment: @purchas if you'd be kind enough to share you complete models. I can refactor it for you and explain you more in details. But here the deal for inlines to work they need to know what "Model" they need to work with.

Comment: @SidharthShah thanks very much I understand now. Those are my complete models, I understand what you mean and what I overlooked, if you want to post the answer, happy to accept it

Comment: @purchas posted answer. Please take a look if its ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The codeInline doesn't have model field for any TabularInline you do need model field like one above. It should have something like following

```
class codeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = vehicleCode
    extra = 0
```

Comment: Comment which I valued most - "But here the deal for inlines to work they need to know what "Model" they need to work with."

Comment: @purchas thank you. This was my first answer getting accepted :)